# should water going through compost come out sudsy (like soap suds)?

Tags: compost, water

I have a composting chamber (similar to a miracle grow container but goes in 1 side and out the other) be sending out water that seems a little sudsy on the output side?

Comment: Can you take a photo of chamber and the sudsy water? That would help

Comment: If i had a smart phone as it's at my community garden. essentially it's a through pipe with a screen filter that has composting material in it. When I need to compost more I will push it closer to the inlet.

Comment: Often. Lignin is foamy: https://nebula.wsimg.com/453698b6056b69eb169d13be10048fc8?AccessKeyId=24369F6DF3178ECDEF1C&disposition=0&alloworigin=1

Answer (score 2):

Suds in agitated water is a sign of a [surfactant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant) in the water.  As Wayfaring Stranger said in a comment, there are [many organic surfactants](https://nebula.wsimg.com/453698b6056b69eb169d13be10048fc8?AccessKeyId=24369F6DF3178ECDEF1C&disposition=0&alloworigin=1) that we would expect to find in compost, so sudsy water would not alarm me without any other signs of issue.  Foaming is often taken as a sign of healthy compost-tea!